# Problems when trying to get Instagram stories through the Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Problems when trying to get Instagram stories through the Graph  API

Getting Insights Data
To get insights data for an individual media object, send a GET request to the /media/insights edge and include the metric parameter with one or more of the metric values you want returned. Please note the following limitations:

Insights data is not available for media objects within album carousels (children).
Stories insights are only available for 24 hours, even if the stories are archived or highlighted. If you want to get the latest insights for a story before it expires, set up a Webhook for the Instagram topic and subscribe to the story_insights field.

For the insights data Things i tried 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/webhooks

Subscribed the App with the POST call from Graph Explorer api 
31231XXXXX/subscribed_apps

How do I Subscribe to the story_insights field of the media object??
Story Metrics
**exits
impressions
reach
replies
taps_forward
taps_back**

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Any solution on this please?